# GettUncaught Error: reCAPTCHA placeholder element must be empty ; loaded only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I'm getting following error on using v2 invisible capcha

> recaptcha__en.js:513 Uncaught Error: reCAPTCHA placeholder element
>   must be empty
>       at YG (recaptcha__en.js:513)
>       at recaptcha__en.js:520
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at pG (recaptcha__en.js:520)
>       at xG (recaptcha__en.js:517)
>       at recaptcha__en.js:507
>       at j$ (recaptcha__en.js:304)
>       at RZ (recaptcha__en.js:507)
>       at recaptcha__en.js:523
>       at recaptcha__en.js:543

I have searched but everywhere it is saying you are loading script multiple times, which I think i'm not doing

[image: Network Activity]

Following is my code

```
    <div class="osnlogin-button">
        <a type="submit" href="" id="recaptcha-submit" class="osnlogin-signin-btn g-recaptcha"><span class="signin lightboxed">Login</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxx" data-bind="recaptcha-submit" data-callback="onCapchaValidated">
    </div>
```

```
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    var onCapchaValidated = function () {
        $('#loginForm').submit();
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed it. Was using "g-recaptcha" class on more than one attribute. I think it should be only on one element in a page.

Original

```
 <div class="osnlogin-button">
    <a type="submit" href="" id="recaptcha-submit" class="osnlogin-signin-btn g-recaptcha"><span class="signin lightboxed">Login</span></a>
</div>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxx" data-bind="recaptcha-submit" data-callback="onCapchaValidated">
</div>
```

Updated

```
<div class="osnlogin-button">
    <a type="submit" href="" id="recaptcha-submit" class="osnlogin-signin-btn"><span class="signin lightboxed">Login</span></a>
</div>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxx" data-bind="recaptcha-submit" data-callback="onCapchaValidated">
</div>
```

It worked finally